# MySQL - inner join on two tables simultaneously

Tags: sql, mysql

I have this join:

```
SELECT * FROM persons p
LEFT JOIN orders o
    ON p.id = o.person_id
LEFT JOIN old_orders oo
    ON p.id = oo.person_id LIMIT 100
```

**orders** and **old_orders** have exactly the same structure and for misc reasons they can't be merged into one table.

Right now, any person with or without orders will be returned, I would like to change those joins into INNER JOIN so the returned persons are only the ones with order history. The problem is 1st inner join will filter out any persons that might have been present in the next one.

I tried to INNER JOIN a UNION of those two tables but the performance hit is just too big since it fetches all rows.

Comment: Simply add `WHERE COALESCE(o.person_id, oo.person_id) IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: Do you want to limit all orders to 100?  Or limit just the old orders?

Comment: @RickJames all orders

Comment: What do you want to show?  (I need some more details to flesh out the query.)  One row per order (with `person` data repeated), whether recent or "old"?

Comment: Is Volchik's answer good?  If not, what is it doing 'wrong'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM persons p
LEFT JOIN orders o
ON p.id = o.person_id
LEFT JOIN old_orders oo
ON p.id = oo.person_id 
WHERE (o.id is not null) or (oo.id is not null) 
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: (Usually a LIMIT needs an ORDER BY.)

Answer (score 1):

Even solving your stated problem, if a p has 3 o rows and 4 oo rows, you are going to end up with 12 rows for that p, where a union would properly get you 7.

The key here is understanding how you want your results ordered before applying the limit; if you truly don't care (as your lack of an order by indicates), do your inner join of a union but apply a limit 100 to both unioned queries (requires parentheses around the second select to keep the limit from only applying to the union as a whole).

If you do care about what order, or are trying to get 100 distinct people, or something else, you need to provide more information.

Comment: (this answer is part answer and part comment but I decided it worked better as the former)